# c# string as column name in sql command 94543

Tags: c#

I have two tables:

Table 1:

```
centers machines
------- --------
center1  machine1
center2  machine2
center2  machine3
```

Table 2:

```
operation center1 center2 center3 ...
--------- ------- ------- ------- ...
oper1     ok       ok
oper2     ok              ok
oper3     ok
```

Selecting a machine (via combobox) from first table, puts me in a center. The operations from Table 2 are specific to each center as shown. So after selecting the machine from table one, passing the center value to a variable like "center" (by Executescalar() method) I want to do:

```
SELECT operation from dbo.operations where "center" != null
```

this should return the only the operations from table 2 which are specific to "center". Does anyone know how this can be achieved?

Comment: You need to more clearly state what you have, what you're trying to do with it, what's not working, in what way it's not working (ie what result are you getting that you didn't expect), and what you've tried, so that we can help you.

Comment: fyi: Comparisons to `NULL` will be disappointing.  Always use `is NULL` to check for `NULL` values.

Answer (score 1):

First, before I actually answer your question, I will point out that you *really really really* need to look into the concept of [normalization](http://databases.about.com/od/specificproducts/a/normalization.htm), and fix your table structure, if that is at all possible. Your Operations table should have three columns - Operation, Center, and Status - having a repeated column like Center1, Center2, Center3 ... is a clear example of bad design. Besides being far more efficient, and more maintainable, a normalized table would eliminate your entire problem of needing the change the column name in your query.

Having said that:

If you're using a `SqlCommand` object to execute your query, and you're assigning a `CommandText` property to that object, you can make the command text whatever you want. You just need to use, for example, `String.Format` to insert the correct column name. You cannot use query parameters to change column names, so you're stuck with dynamically generating your SQL statements:

```
cmd.CommandText = string.Format("SELECT operation FROM dbo.Operations WHERE {0} IS NOT NULL", center);
```

Note that *nothing* will ever be `!= NULL`: all comparisons against `NULL` in SQL return false (that is, `1 = NULL` is false and `1 != NULL` is also false). You need to use `IS` and `IS NOT` to compare to `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what language you're working with, but I can't think of one that would allow you to parameterize column names.

To do what you're trying to do, you would have to use [dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html) which can be very dangerous if you don't know what you're doing, so proceed at your own risk.